# MySQL - Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

So, I create a new user

```
CREATE USER servname_shb IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Grant him all the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO servname_shb;
```

No errors so far. Then I try to connect to database:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "servname_shbusers";
$dbuser = "servname_shb";
$dbpass = "password";

$c = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Error:".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Error connecting to databse:".mysql_error());
```

And get an error:

```
Access denied for user 'servname_shb'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in <path>
```

I tried FLUSH PRIVILEGES, dropping and recreating user - no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wondering, if "%" stands for ANY server, why the hell it doesnt cover localhost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error messages gives you a hint already. Use this grant statement:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'servname_shb'@'localhost';
```

Or better, as @grantk points out in the comments, refine the access scope to only what is actually needed.

Comment: Do not grant all to every database in the server. Just grant that user permissions for the database/tables they need access too.

Comment: Works just fine =) Forgot to create user in the same way (@'localhost')

Comment: Can this be done to the user inserted into a particular database using `INSERT INTO ` clause? I mean if a user isn't created using `CREATE USER ` command.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `'servname_shb'@'localhost'` as the username. Your request become:

```
CREATE USER 'servname_shb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'servname_shb'@'localhost';
```

Note: `'servname_shb'@'localhost'` only allow connection from localhost. You can use `'servname_shb'@'%'` to allow connection from everywhere.

Comment: this solution need an access with a granted user !