# Error when importing MySQL through PHPadmin

Tags: mysql

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL said:

```
View Full Image 
#1044
 - Access denied for user 'mydatabasenamehere'@'%' to database 'information_schema'
```

I've been told I don't have the right credentials/privileges. Ok. But where do I change them? The database was exported and then I changed the URL for my new site so I will have an exact copy of the original database. When I upload I get the above message.

I have access to both databases and both passwords. So where do I make the info right so I can import it without errors?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875831/mysql-access-denied-for-user

Answer (score 0):

Your script is attempting to insert into [system tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html), which is forbidden:

> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

The question you should ask yourself is : why is your database backup containing these tables?

Answer (score 0):

You should cut cut of `information_schema`, `mysql` and `performance_schema` from your dump before import.

- May be it would be easier for you to make dump once again using `mysqldump` command utility and than restore it.
- Another option it use `grep`, `head`, `tail`(*nix) or `PowerShell` (Windows) to extract database you need from your dump file.