# mysql access denied while creating new user

Tags: mysql, command-line

I want to create a new mysql user and database demo **in my company**. Here is the commands i input in the mysql.exe :

```
create user 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'admin';
create database dem;
```

Everytime i have that response:

> access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database.

Actually i refered to that similar question :

- [MySQL - Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875831/mysql-access-denied-for-user)

Can anyone help please ???

Comment: Under which user (if any) are you running mysql? And does that user have rights to create users and databases?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating the database *first* then you can create a user, and use the GRANT option to allow permissions to that user for whatever you find necessary.  However, creating a user first then a database while it's able to "potentially" work, isn't the best practice with MySQL.  So you want to effectively do the Steps as such:

1. Create Database
2. Create User
3. GRANT permissions
4. ???
5. Profit

Comment: Thnx for your response. For each operation you suggested I have this response from the command line : "Access denied" OR "error in your SQL syntax"

Answer (score 0):

You have to GRANT access to admin for dem.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You may have to also GRANT the same for admin@localhost as well. IIRC if you ever logon remotely with admin you would inherit the base privileges unless otherwise GRANTed

You can find many answers [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/adding-users.html).

Comment: thnx for your answer. I input the grant command this the error i got : "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: That's right out of the online MySQL reference. Look at my edits, that should execute now. That will work, but opens it up a little wide on security. Get beyond your issue here and then you can revist how to create and authorize users. I added a link to my answer.