# MySQL, root no longer has privileges despite not doing anything different

Tags: mysql, easyphp

EDIT: I have worked out what the problem was. When logging in using command prompt I was typing -u root; . The semicolon was the problem. Without the semicolon it works as expected.

I'm using `easyphp` and working my way through "**Learning PHP, MySQL and *Javascript***" by Robin Nixon.

I'm trying to follow along with the book I tried to create a database, but it said access denied. I uninstalled easyphp and installed the latest version. Then everything worked fine and I could go along with the book. Two days later, I'm getting the access denied message again.

```
"Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql' "
```

I've not changed anything. I looked at PHPMyAamin (which i haven't really learned how to use yet), and it says root localhost has all privileges. I've reinsalled easyphp but it's still the same.

I've tried turning off windows firewall completely and I still have this problem. I've looked up many topics similar but I'm still struggling.

Anyone know what this could be? If not, is it possible for me to proceed not using command prompt and just using `PhPMyAdmin`? I've been stuck on this too long.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875831/mysql-access-denied-for-user) question may help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had seen that one. I tried entering "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '@'localhost'; But I just get access denied.

Comment: By the way, why is your **user** blank? The answer's syntax is `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '` **user** `'@'localhost'`

Comment: Do I actually type 'user' or something in place of that? I've tried adding user and I still get access denied. If it's not user then what do I put there? I haven't created any users? Sorry, i'm very new to MySql.

Comment: I mean you should investigate why MySQL is not seeing a username that's trying to access it.

Comment: In the error message it says. ''@'localhost'. But should it not say 'root@localhost' ?. Is that what you mean by not seeing a username that's trying to access it?

Comment: Yes. Please show the code where you're trying to access the database.

Comment: I'm just using command prompt. So I type this "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql" -u root;

Comment: That works fine as expected. But when I try to create a database or just about do anything it says access denied.

Comment: It's working now. I think it was because I was adding a semicolon! In the book I'm using there is no semicolon after the -u root. Anyway thanks so much for your time and patience Nath.

Comment: It's nice to know it's working. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with this:

`mysql -p -u root`

When asked for a password, leave it blank and then press enter.