MySQL connection issues with Deno
In Deno I'm using this module https://deno.land/x/mysql@v2.12.1/mod.ts to connect to mySQL 8 database in Windows 10 and generally it works fine.
However, after a fresh start or reboot, when it tries to connect to the DB I get the following error:
Uncaught (in worker "") (in promise) Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)      throw new Error(error.message);

I keep getting the same error until I connect to the db with MySQL Workbench. After that, then Deno can successfully connect to the DB even if I close MySQL Workbench, until next reboot.

Have a look at this question. It sounds quite similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561854/mysql-access-denied-until-i-connect-via-workbench-or-cli
